# Macro like `\ignorespaces` for ignoring `\par`s

Tags: macros, plain-tex

I would like to have a macro `\ignorepars` that removes all `\par`s following it.  I wrote the following code:

```
\def\eat{}
\def\ignorepars{\futurelet\next\ignoreparsA} 
\def\ignoreparsA{\ifx\next\par\expandafter\ignorepars\eat\fi}
```

but it does not work (it causes a TeX capacity exceeded error).
Suppose, for example, I have `\ignorepars\par x`.  Then, according to me, the expansion of `\ignorepars` makes `\next` like `\par` and the token list becomes `\ignoreparsA\par x`; next after expanding `\ignoreparsA` it remains `\expandafter\ignorepars\eat\par x`;  so, after another expansion the token list becomes `\ignorepars x`; which make `\next` have the value x and expands to `\ignoreparsA x`; this expands to nothing becase the `\ifx` predicate is false.

What is happening instead?

EDIT:  `\def\eat{}` should have been `\long\def\eat#1{}`  (it was a typing error)

Comment: `\eat` should take a paramater to actually eat something, i.e. `\def\eat#1{}`.

Comment: and (if i understand) `\eat` should be `\long`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Let's do it slowly:

```
\ignorepars\par x
```

becomes

```
\futurelet\next\ignoreparsA\par x
```

Now `\next` is `\let` to `\par` and `\ignoreparsA` is expanded, so we have

```
\ifx\next\par\expandafter\ignorepars\eat\fi\par x
```

The conditional is true, so `\ifx\next\par` disappear, leaving

```
\expandafter\ignorepars\eat\fi\par x
```

Now `\expandafter` expands `\eat`, which has empty expansion, so we have

```
\ignorepars\fi\par x
```

OK, `\ignorepars` is expanded:

```
\futurelet\next\ignoreparsA\fi\par x
```

Now `\next` is `\let` to `\fi` and `\ignoreparsA` is expanded

```
\ifx\next\par\expandafter\ignorepars\eat\fi\fi\par x
```

The conditional is false, so we get

```
\fi\par x
```

Finally, the expansion of `\fi` is empty. So, as you see, no `\par` is swallowed. Indeed, the test file

```
\def\eat{}
\def\ignorepars{\futurelet\next\ignoreparsA}
\def\ignoreparsA{\ifx\next\par\expandafter\ignorepars\eat\fi}

x\ignorepars\par x

\bye
```

does not end up in TeX capacity exceeded, but prints two paragraphs.

If your definition of `\eat` is

```
\def\eat#1{}
```

then you'll indeed get into an infinite loop, because `\eat` will gobble `\fi` and present TeX with `\ignorepars\par` again and again.

---

You have better luck with

```
\long\def\eat#1{\ignorepars}
\def\ignorepars{\futurelet\next\ignoreparsA}
\def\ignoreparsA{\ifx\next\par\expandafter\eat\fi}

x\ignorepars\par x

\bye
```

The `\expandafter` gets rid of `\fi`, whereas `\eat` gobbles the `\par` token and supplies `\ignorepars`.

Test file

```
\long\def\eat#1{\ignorepars}
\def\ignorepars{\futurelet\next\ignoreparsA}
\def\ignoreparsA{\ifx\next\par\expandafter\eat\fi}

x\ignorepars\par x

y\ignorepars

y

z\ignorepars



z

\bye
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to copy the #1 in eat.  (If it was right it would happen the TeX Capacity error).  The problem was that I thought that \fi disappears after expanding the conditional.  Thanks

Comment: @User I added a comment about the different definition; you should be able to see what's going wrong.

Answer (score 8):

this has lots less finesse than egreg's suggestion, but sometimes
brute force works.

```
\let\oldpar\par
\def\ignorepar{\let\par\ignorespaces}
\def\restorepar{\endgraf\let\par\oldpar}
\def\bye{\endgraf\end}

\ignorepar

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

\restorepar

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

\ignorepar

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

\restorepar

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

abcdef ghijkl mnopqr stuv wxyz

\bye
```

Answer (score 4):

Spaces need special treatment to be ignored as they are character tokens but `\par` is a csname so you can more simply do  `\let\par\empty`  (which latex does for example in `tabular`) (obviously you need some hook such as end of group to restore the definition if `\par` is ignored in this manner.)