# Positioning text under section

Tags: sectioning

CODE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}  
\usepackage{rotating}  
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{  
  \begin{sideways}%  
  #1%  
  \end{sideways}  
}  
\begin{document}   

\section{publications}  
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\  
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB\\  
CCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\

\end{document}  
\end{document}
```

The ABC text block will be under the section text,
how can I make to looks like this:
[image: pic2]

Comment: Just to fully understand, you are using the "ABC" as aplaceholder for generic full-width wrapping text, is that correct?

Answer (score 3):

Rather than renew `\section`, I just called it `\mysection`, because the renewal proposed by the OP destroys LaTeX's sectioning mechanism (which may or may not be needed for the OP's application).  [This is more like a `\section*` anyway]

EDITED to account for `\parskip`, if employed.

RE-EDITED to account for barbara's suggestion to have the material not indented for the 1st paragraph of the new `\mysection`.  To accomplish this, I asked a question , [Ignore \par after the end of a macro; THEN insert \noindent](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329949/ignore-par-after-the-end-of-a-macro-then-insert-noindent), and David came to the rescue with `\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading`.

```
\documentclass[]{article}  
\usepackage{rotating,stackengine,lipsum}  
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\par\noindent\llap{\smash{%
  \belowbaseline[\dimexpr\baselineskip-.8\ht\strutbox\relax]{%
  \rotatebox{90}{#1}}}\hspace{7pt}}\par%
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother 
\setstackEOL{\cr} 
\begin{document}   

\mysection{publications}

\lipsum[1]

\mysection{\Longstack[r]{a longer\cr title name}}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I know the OP didn't requested so, but won't this leave the ToC empty?

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Indeed it will, which is why I did not rename it `\section`.  Of course, the fact that it is unnumbered make it a sort of `\section*` to begin with.  Furthermore, the context of the "publications" tag leads one to think it is part of a resume or cv or something along those lines, where tocs are not employed.

Comment: Taking into account the OP format request, you are probably right. It is just that you mentioned the ToC in your answer so I thought making one was implied.

Comment: @GuilhermeZ.Santos Good point.  I have edited to clarify

Comment: not entirely clear, but i think the indentation of the first paragraph after the section heading isn't wanted.

Comment: @barbarabeeton Probably so.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to skip over a `\par` in the user input.  For example, ending the `\mysection` definition with `...\par\noindent\ignorespaces}` would take care of my 2nd section, but not my 1st, since the input presents an extra blank line.  Obviously, a manual `\noindent` can always be added to the user input.

Comment: @barbarabeeton even the answers (including yours) at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279652/macro-like-ignorespaces-for-ignoring-pars don't seem to help, since I am trying to invoke it inside a macro to ignore `\par` after leaving the macro, but then restore the definition as soon as I hit text.

Comment: i *think* `\@afterindentfalse` is the command that turns it off.  (having trouble finding documentation; not in the companion.)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two solutions with `titlesec`, which adds the section to the toc:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry} 
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 
\usepackage{rotating, graphicx}
\usepackage[explicit]{titlesec}
\usepackage{lettrine}


\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\vspace{1cm}
 \titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[wrap]{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\raisebox{-0.67\height}{\begin{sideways}%
\color{IndianRed}#1 \end{sideways}}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\MakeUppercase#1}}

\section*{publications}
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB\\
CCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\
\vspace{1cm}

 \titleformat{name=\section, numberless}[leftmargin]{\large\bfseries}{}{0pt}{\llap{\raisebox{0.5cm}{\rotatebox[origin=tr]{90}{ %
 \color{IndianRed}#1}\hspace{-0.33em}}}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\MakeUppercase#1}}

\section*{publications}
AAAAAAAAAAAAAA\\
BBBBBBBBBBBBBB\\
CCCCCCCCCCCCCC\\

\end{document}
```

[image]