# Ignore \par after the end of a macro; THEN insert \noindent

Tags: indentation, paragraphs

In my answer to [Positioning text under section](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329919/positioning-text-under-section), barbara beeton commented that perhaps I should have the first paragraph following this new "section-like" definition be non-indented.

True, I agreed, but I didn't know how to swallow `\par`.  I discovered this question, [Macro like `\ignorespaces` for ignoring `\par`s](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279652/macro-like-ignorespaces-for-ignoring-pars), and egreg's answer to it looked most promising.  I was actually surprised that a ready-made TeX solution was not at hand (maybe there is one for LaTeX)

I tried to adapt it to make subsequent text non-indented.  I could only succeed when no `\par`s occurred after the section-like invocation.  My approach was to take egreg's `\futurelet`/`\eat` approach, and tack on a `\else\expandafter\shazam` before the final `\fi` of his `\ignoreparsA` macro, where `\shazam` is defined as `\def\shazam{\noindent\expandafter\ignorespaces}`.  As mentioned, this does not work when `\par`s occur after a `\mysection` invocation.

```
\documentclass[]{article}  
\usepackage{rotating,stackengine,lipsum}  
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\leavevmode\llap{\smash{%
  \belowbaseline[\dimexpr\baselineskip-.8\ht\strutbox\relax]{%
  \rotatebox{90}{#1}}}\hspace{5.5ex}}\par%
  \def\shazam{\noindent\expandafter\ignorespaces}%
  \expandafter\ignorepars}
\setstackEOL{\cr} 
% modified egreg's answer from
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279652/macro-like-ignorespaces-for-ignoring-pars
% Trying to end on a \noindent, without success
\long\def\eat#1{\ignorepars}
\def\ignorepars{\futurelet\next\ignoreparsA}
\def\ignoreparsA{\ifx\next\par\expandafter\eat\else\expandafter\shazam\fi}

\begin{document}   

\mysection{publications}

\lipsum[1]

\mysection{\Longstack[r]{a longer\cr title name}}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```

[image]

I don't know if the OP (enax) of the cited question needs a `\noindent` or not, but it seems like a useful thing to have, to be able to ignore `\par` and THEN issue a `\noindent`.

Comment: your `\ifx\next\par\expandafter\eat\fi\expandafter\shazam` looks strange. Is the `\eat` supposed to gobble the `\expandafter`. You probably meant `\eat\else\expandafter\shazam\fi}`. Besides, LaTeX2e has its way of implementing the no indent after section. Look at F: ltsect.dtx in source2e. Especially `\@afterheading`.

Comment: @jfbu Yes, you are right...but it still does not remedy the issue.  I will follow your other leads

Comment: note that suppressing indentation using `\noindent` is rarely what you want to do (latex never uses `\noindent` to suppress indentation after headings or list items or displayed math or lists).  You should use `\@afterheading` which will _remove_ indentation once the next paragraph starts. (rather than `\noindent` which would start a paragraph without indentation.)

Comment: use `\@afterindentfalse` and `\@afterheading` from inside your alternate section code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just want to call `\@afterindentfalse\@afterheading` Also I removed the paragraph indentation from the heading offset

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}  
\usepackage{rotating,stackengine,lipsum}  
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mysection}[1]{\par\noindent\llap{\smash{%
  \belowbaseline[\dimexpr\baselineskip-.8\ht\strutbox\relax]{%
  \rotatebox{90}{#1}}}\hspace{5pt}}\par%
  \@afterindentfalse\@afterheading}
\makeatother
\setstackEOL{\cr} 
% modified egreg's answer from
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279652/macro-like-ignorespaces-for-ignoring-pars
% Trying to end on a \noindent, without success


\begin{document}   

\mysection{publications}


\lipsum[1]

\mysection{\Longstack[r]{a longer\cr title name}}
\lipsum[4]
\end{document}
```