# No indentation for first paragraph after poem/verse environment

Tags: indentation, verse, noindentafter

I am working on project which contains many verses and prose with its meaning. I want first paragraph after each verse to be unindented but following paragraphs indented. How to achieve it through out document?

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}

‘Me’ and ‘mine’ were both forgotten I \\
And the world was whisked away;\\
Yet there was a bliss compareless, \\
Boundless, as asleep I lay.
\end{verse}

 \noindent Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing
vitae, felis.

mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
 consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellen
tesque habitant morbi tristique senectus

\begin{verse}
The azure vault with stars studded,\\
And green vestured earth so fair. \\
Objects all were clean out-blotted \\
Only self was glowing there.
\end{verse}

et netus et malesuada fames ac tur
pis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra me-
tus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus v
estibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus

eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida 
placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent e
get sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, males
uada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur

\end{document}
```

[image: Poem]

Comment: The TeX rule is that a blank line ends a paragraph and starts a new one (with its indent). If you don't want a new paragraph, don't use a blank line. LaTeX is not HTML

Answer (score 1):

Just place a `%` on the blank line between the end of the `verse` and the following text, or else eliminate the blank line altogether.  This, of course, amounts to following the rules of LaTeX.

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{verse}

‘Me’ and ‘mine’ were both forgotten I \\
And the world was whisked away;\\
Yet there was a bliss compareless, \\
Boundless, as asleep I lay.
\end{verse}
%
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer
adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit,
vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing
vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida

mauris. Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget,
 consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna.
Donec vehicula augue eu neque. Pellen
tesque habitant morbi tristique senectus

\begin{verse}
The azure vault with stars studded,\\
And green vestured earth so fair. \\
Objects all were clean out-blotted \\
Only self was glowing there.
\end{verse}
%
et netus et malesuada fames ac tur
pis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra me-
tus rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus v
estibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus

eu tellus sit amet tortor gravida 
placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent e
get sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, males
uada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have clarified my question also updated the output image

Comment: @Ramaprakasha I will delete my answer, unless I solve the clarified problem

Comment: @Ramaprakasha I have revised my answer

Comment: I was looking for a CSS like solution `p:first-of-type { text-indent: 0em; }` that means hacking verse environment so first para is always unindented.

Comment: @Ramaprakasha I was hoping that this question, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/329949/ignore-par-after-the-end-of-a-macro-then-insert-noindent, might provide a way, but so far I have not been able to adapt the answer.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Hi, I vote your question. Now is +1 :-).

Comment: @Sebastiano I know it wasn't the answer the OP wanted to hear, but an editor could take care of it in no time, even for a large document, and it really is the right way to proceed.