# Ignoring \par commands with \renewcommand{\par}{}?

Tags: spacing, macros, paragraphs

I would like to ignore `\par` commands in a predefined LaTeX file. I simply tried:

```
\renewcommand{\par}{}
```

but this does not work as `\par` is ending the paragraph within the `\renewcommand` command.

```
! Paragraph ended before \renew@command was complete.
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. And congratulations to have found a way to shoot yourself into your foot  with this idea ;-) Sorry!

Comment: This seems like it could go wrong in many different ways.  Why are you wanting to redefine `\par`?

Comment: Maybe it is better to do a search and replace with your editor. You can also run a script to do that (`sed`, ...). Not everything has to be done within TeX. And redefining `\par` seems like a particularly risky idea.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/279657/35864 - but it is not recommended to have this on in the entire document.

Comment: I have automatically-generated tex files (with doxygen) and  spurious \par commands are inserted because of \n occurrences. The problem can be treated at the source code level but I was wondering if this could simply be done at the tex level.

Comment: I'd say it is more dangerous at the TeX level than to fix the input that causes the unwanted `.tex` code.

Comment: You can do `\def\par{}`; then wait until TeX exits from some infinite loop. `:-)` Really, it's a *very* dangerous thing to do, because in several occasions TeX inserts `\par` automatically and in such circumstances it may not exit from the loop.

Comment: why would you want to do this? (latex will not be able to work at all)

Answer (score 7):

You can easily redefine `\par`:

```
\def\par{}
```

But it is only safe to do this in very controlled contexts, for example:

**This document will not terminate and you will need to kill the process**

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\par{}

aaaaa

\hrule

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is there a way to completely un-hardcode things from TeX? Or is somehow `\par` (or some other thing) entirely hardcodded?

Comment: @Manuel many aspects of `\par` are hardcoded,  (so that the behaviour can be customised) when tex needs to end a paragraph it does not (normally) use the primitive end-of-para action it simply inserts `\par`  (as it does at a blank line) so this allows you to define `\par` to do interesting things, but if (as here) those things do not include ending a paragraph then things can easily go wrong, here it sees `\hrule` so needs to get out of hmode, so inserts a `\par` then it sees `\hrule` so inserts a `\par` then..

Comment: So in TeX there's no way to tell TeX to never use an explicit `\par` and rather use its meaning (or `\engraf` or an alternative)? Are there more things that are *hardcoded* into the program?

Comment: @Manuel as far as I can think `\par` is the _only_ command name that can not be changed any other primitive you can save the primitive under another name then redefine the original name to be anything (or make it undefined) but tex itself inserts `\par` tokens

Answer (score 1):

The best course could be to redefine `\par` inside a group. For example

```
\newenvironment{specialpar}{\def\par{\ \P\ }}{\endgraf}
```

And then that way you can do

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for this example

\newenvironment{specialpar}{\def\par{\ \P\ }}{\endgraf}

\begin{document}

\begin{specialpar}
  Whatever you want, but knowing that \texttt{\string\par} is a special thing in here,
  so your input must be controlled. \par
  This. \par
  That. \par
  And many other things, but beware of errors.

  Another paragraph.

  And yet another.

  \kant
\end{specialpar}

\end{document}
```

PS: note that if you pile a lot of things in the same “TeX paragraph” (that is, before adding the original `\par` or `\engraf` for instance) this is piling in memory and makes TeX work much more (the program kind of breathes each time he processes a proper paragraph).