# Infinite compilation with minted, bgcolor, and disabling \let\par\relax

Tags: errors, paragraphs, minted, compilation-error, texlive-2019

I had defined an environment which disabled `\par` temporarily with `\let\par\relax` precisely to disallow paragraph breaks in that environment. It was working fine until I last compiled the document (mid 2018), but now (with TeXLive 2019) it gets stuck into an infinite compilation.

I managed to strip down the problem to a code (at the bottom of this post) that uses only the `minted` package with `\setminted{bgcolor=white}` and my `nopar` environment.

If I comment out `\let\par\relax` the document compiles fine, but I need to disable `\par` here (unless, of course, there is another way to disallow paragraph breaks, in which case I'd accept as an answer). If I comment out `\setminted{bgcolor=white}` then I get the fearsome `Missing \item` error. If I comment out the text before `\begin{minted}` it works as well, but I can't do that.

Here's the guilty code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\setminted{bgcolor=white}
\newenvironment{nopar}{%
  \let\par\relax}{}
\begin{document}
\begin{nopar}
  hello
  \begin{minted}{latex}
    world
  \end{minted}
\end{nopar}
\end{document}
```

Comment: What would be the purpose of disabling `\par`? Are you perhaps trying to typeset the `minted` part in line? Then `Hello \mintinline{latex}{world}` should suffice.

Comment: By the way, I get an infinite loop with all TeX Live releases from 2016 onwards; only TL 2015 compiles, but with a very disputable output.

Comment: This is very confusing. What exactly are you hoping your environment is going to do? Do you just don't like the indent, that par does? Just use \noindent. Do you just don't like the extra empty line? Use \newline.  Do you want an empty line, but not with par? Use \vspace{"Enter Number with units"}. Or am I missing another option?

Comment: @egreg Sorry if I didn't express myself right. This is only a stripped down example. In the actual document I have an environment which is not supposed to have paragraph breaks, and in the middle of it there is a block of code (not inline). I disable `\par` because this package is supposed to be used by other people and I want to ensure that there will be no paragraph breaks. Of course I can simply remove the blank lines, but I'd rather make the code work with `\par` disabled. However, if you know some other form of disallowing paragraph breaks inside an environment, I'd be open to change!

Comment: @DonFangzahn No, it's not about the indentation. I know I can set `\parindent=0pt` as well inside the environment. The thing is, as I (hopefully :) explained in the comment to egreg, that I want the text inside the `nopar` environment to _not_ have paragraph breaks, even if the user inserts a blank line (of course, if one wants to be stubborn, one can use `\endgraf`). The text in the environment is supposed to be a single, long paragraph.

Comment: @LateXer Then I would suggest setlength{\parskip}{.0\baselineskip} instead of let\par\relax in your einvironment. It might be, that even setlength{\parskip}{0mm} is an option. But I didn't try that

Comment: @DonFangzahn Yes, I thought of that. However the lines that end paragraphs are still ragged right, whereas if I `\let\par\relax` then the second paragraph is appended to the first. The effect _is_ different, unfortunately.

Comment: So you want something like that: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/279652/macro-like-ignorespaces-for-ignoring-pars
Me personally, i like the answer \let\par\empty in that thread.

Comment: @DonFangzahn Yes, something like that. I would like something like barbarabeeton's solution, which you can easily make into an environment using `\ignorepar` and `\restorepar`. However both hers and David Carlisle's solution (with `\let\par\empty`) result in an infinite compilation. egreg's solution doesn't do that but requires me to put `\ignorepars` every time, which would make it easier to just remove the blank lines...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure what's the purpose of `\let\par\relax` in a context where `minted` is allowed.

Anyway, use `etoolbox` to restore `\par` in the `minted` environment.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginEnvironment{minted}{\let\par\@@par}
\makeatother

\setminted{bgcolor=white}

\newenvironment{nopar}{\let\par\relax}{}

\begin{document}

\begin{nopar}
  hello
  \begin{minted}{latex}
    world
  \end{minted}
  again

  Again
\end{nopar}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The intention of the code in the question is very unclear but redefining `\par` to anything is highly likely to throw LaTeX into an infinite loop or break it in other ways.

In some highly controlled environments it can be a useful technique but never in environments taking arbitrary LaTeX content. Your example loops on including the rather complex minted code, but this trivial example also loops.

When TeX sees a command that should be in vertical mode (there are lots of these, but I used `\vskip` here) when it is not in `vmode`, it inserts `\par`  to try to start the `vmode` and tries the command again. If you disable `\par` it loops... This is built into TeX-the-program so it is not under LaTeX control.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

{\let\par\relax

a  \vskip 2pt

}


\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Can you please explain what happens here that makes the code loop forever?

Comment: @LaTeXer tex sees a command that should be in vertical mode (there are lots of these, but vskip here) when it is not in vmode, so it inserts `\par` and tries again, if you disable `\par` it loops.......  this is built into tex-the-program so not under latex control.

Comment: I think I understand. Thanks a lot for the explanation! I will accept egreg's answer because it solves the issue, ok? However seeing how fragile this is I think I will un-disable `\par`. Doesn't look that good an idea anymore...

Comment: @LaTeXer oh no, disaster! (giving the tick to egreg:-)

Comment: Oh no! :) Your answer is more interesting, I must say ;)